# Can you recommend a Windows based Network emulator?

Tags: networking, wireless

I'm looking for a Windows network emulator that can emulate the packet-loss & latency characteristics of a 3G wireless network.

I used to use a tool from GIPs that has been end-of-life'd. I've also tried Shunra Virtual Enterprise but found it a bit too basic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a FreeBSD tool called dummynet that can do this.  Since you have a Windows setup, you could put it on a separate box and route through it for testing, or perhaps even run it on a VM on your Windows machine.  I know of no Windows solution to this problem, but perhaps others will.

Comment: I did't understand this answer. Can you describe it in clear way, What to do here?

Answer (score 5):

dummynet is now available for windows and linux as well. See
http://info.iet.unipi.it/~luigi/dummynet/

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried LANforge ICE for Windows? http://www.candelatech.com/lanforge_v3/datasheet.html#ice

Comment: I would recommend LANforge for windows, and LANforge for Linux even more.